# Error C3861: 'decrypt' not found even with function in header

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, runtime-error

The code I have loads a encrypted text file, with the first line of this text file being a cipher that is used to decode the rest of the text file. I know that this error usually happens if the function isn't defined before main, but I have it defined in the header, so i'm not sure what is causing this problem.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 

std::string decrypt(std::string cipher, std::string text);

int main()
{
//variable
std::string fileName; 
std::string cipher; 
std::string text;   

//prompt the user to enter the file name
std::cout << "Enter file name: "; 
std::cin  >> fileName;

//declare input stream
std::ifstream inFile(fileName); 

//Checks if the file has been connected or not
if (inFile.is_open()) 
{ 
    std::cout << "File found." << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "Processing..." << std::endl; 

    getline(inFile,cipher); //get the first line as one string
    std::cout << cipher << std::endl;  //TEST!!!!
    std::cout << "\n" << std::endl; //TEST!!!!!!

    while (inFile.good()) //continue running until an error occurs to get the rest of the text as second string
    {
        getline(inFile,text); //get the first line as one string
        std::cout << text << std::endl; //TEST!!!!
    }       
} 
else //if the file isn't connected
{ 
    std::cout << "File not found." << std::endl;    **(ERROR C3861 HERE)**
}

inFile.close(); //close the file

std::string finalResult = decrypt(cipher,text);
std:: cout << finalResult << std::endl;

return 0;
}

//Decrypt function: Takes 2 strings by reference, changes the second string into the    unencrypted text
std::string decrypt(std::string cipher, std::string text)
{

char alphabet[27] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; //create a character array of the alphabet 
char code[27]; //empty array 
char oldText[500]; //empty array 
strcpy(code,cipher.c_str()); //copies the cipher into the array
strcpy(oldText,text.c_str()); //copies the encrypted text into the array

for (int i = 0; i < 500;i++) //Loop through the entire encrypted text
{
    int k = i; //creates and resets a variable for while loop
    while (alphabet[k] != oldText[i])
    {
        k = k+1; 
    }
    oldText[i] = alphabet[k]; //after a match is detected, swap the letters
}

std::string newText(oldText); // converts the array back into text
return newText;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line in `decrypt`:

```
 std::string text(oldText); // converts the array back into text
```

It does not convert 'oldText' back into `text`; instead it declare a new local variable named `test`.  That new local variable conflicts with the parameter named `text`.  This is the line that is causing the `C2082`.  What you should have written is:

```
text = oldText;
```

Which is replace the contents of `test` with what is in `oldText`  Although it would be simpler to skip that entirely and just `return oldText`.

I don't get a `C3861` when compling your code, plus the fact that you are showing the `C2082` on the wrong line makes me think your source file is out of sync with your errors.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have fixed the C2082, however, I still get an error with the C3861. I tried copying the cold back into a new cpp file, and I still get the error. This time, it says the error is on row 45  "getline(inFile,text); //get the first line as one string"

Comment: @user3550643 **`std::getline`**